# Expected type 'string'. Found 'array'.intelephense(1006) laravel

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

i need to assign room number string value into `$rooms_db` variable and explode it using , and assign the seperated values in to `$rooms_arr`. but there is a error says `that:::: Expected type 'string'. Found 'array'.intelephense(1006)` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvhwz.png)

code is :

```
 $rooms_db = DB::SELECT("SELECT room_number FROM bookings WHERE '$checkin_date' BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkout_date ");
           
 $room_arr =explode(",",$rooms_db);
    
 return response()->json(['data'=>$room_arr]);
```

i am very new to programming.  can you solve this problem . thank you

Comment: What is the value of $rooms_db? It has to be a string, not an array.

Comment: it is ll,11E from roomnumber table

Answer (score 1):

You query result ($rooms_db) is type of array of object, not a string.
So no need to explode.
Please use this stuff instead of `explode`

```
$room_arr = array_map(function($item) { return $item->room_number; }, $room_db);
```

Comment: $rooms_db = DB::SELECT("SELECT room_number FROM bookings WHERE '$checkin_date' BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkout_date ");
       $room_arr = array_map(function($item) { return $item->room_number; }, $rooms_db);
    //    $room_ = explode(",",$room_arr);


       return response()->json(['data'=>$room_arr]);      $rooms_db is ll,11E from room_number colmn. but it is not exploded to seperated values after using your code.   here is console....   {data: Array(1)}
data: Array(1)
0: "ll,11E"
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: What is this? @nadeesha